# EC2 Instance Unavailable After Connecting to VPN

Tags: amazon-ec2, vpn

Right after we installed a VPN program (Network Connect from Juniper) on our EC2 instance (Windows 2016 Basic) and clicked on *Start*, the EC2 becomes unavailable. We reboot the machine. The problem persists and we cannot access the VPN. The VPN application works only in Windows and that's why we are trying AWS EC2. What could cause this and is there a way around it?

At first we thought it's probably because we used the free tier version and the instance is weak and the single CPU cannot handle time-outs. So we created a new instance (`t2.medium` with 2 CPUs and 4GB of RAM). But we get the same results there. *Event Viewer* does not say much either.

**Update 1:**
Security Group's Inbound Rules
[image]

**Update 2:**
CPU Credit Balance
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can attach an Elastic IP to that instance that will not remove on the restart and have you verified you VPN client network and aws instance network where not conflicting.

Comment: Thanks for the Elastic IP solution. That problem is solved. Could you explain your second point please? The VPN program is called **Network Connect**. It is installed _inside_ the EC2. So we access another remote desktop via the EC2. And the connection there seems to time-out and that's why the EC2 becomes temporarily unavailable (it comes back after a while). The logs are not very clear. But could the unresponsive GUI be due to the fact that the EC2 has only one CPU?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with your IP address changing every time you reboot your machine then you should attach an Elastic IP to it. This will get a static IP to your machine, it won't change after a reboot.

Also take a look to your VPN program, once installed it may be setting some rules to access to your machine that are not allowed in your security group on AWS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html

Comment: The outbound traffic of my security group is all open. The inbound traffic has one Custom TCP Rule, Port Range 3389, Source 0.0.0.0/0. Does anything look suspicious?

Comment: Don't know why you set 3389 port, I guess it's because your windows system needs it (I've read that this port is used by RDP protocol). If you're serving a webpage then you'll need to add this rule: HTTP (port 80 and source 0.0.0.0/0) otherwise your machine won't be accessible from the outside. Also, if users access via https to your website, you'll need to add HTTPS (port 443 and source 0.0.0.0/0) rule. The outbound traffic it's okay.

Comment: I updated the question with the current inbound rules. The server did not start without the 3389 port rule. I also added the HTTP rule you mentioned as well as the HTTPS rule (even though it switches back to _Custom TCP_ when I click on Save. The problem persists when VPN is connected. Is there something else we can do to check? Meanwhile, I can go check the event log.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: The problem does not happen outside the EC2. We have access to the EC2 machine. It's when we start a program called *Network Connect* and try to login to the remote VPN that we see a black screen that says "Connection to remote PC was lost". I suspect this is a Time-out problem with the Network Connect program. Could it be because the machine has only one CPU and cannot manage time-outs in a good way? The machine comes back to life after a while when we connect again. I see nothing suspicious in event logs, either.

Comment: Can you check in: EC2 Dashboard > Instances (select your EC2 instance here) > Monitoring > CPU Credit Balance. Check if this at some point in the last few hours/days, is falling down to 0.

Comment: I don't think so. Updated the question with CPU credit balance for the last week. FYI This is a new instance, started started as of yesterday.

Comment: You said you suspect the problem's about the machine having only one CPU, why don't you change your instance type to one with 2 cores or more (t2.medium for instance) and see what happens? But be careful,  because t2.medium is not in the free tier.

Comment: That is exactly why I don't dare switch, because I am only allowed to test the EC2 to see if this is a working solution. But regardless, I don't understand why a time-out from an application must freeze an entire OS GUI.

Comment: Are you able to connect via SSH to your EC2 after it freezes?

Comment: Now I have also created a second instance with 2 CPUs and 4 GB of RAM. The VPN program (Network connect from Juniper) still causes the machine to freeze. Unfortunately, the problem does not leave a trace in logs, so it's very hard to troubleshoot the idea.

Comment: Even though it seems to be a time-out problem, I just don't understand why the instance should freeze and become unavailable unless we reboot.

Comment: It happened something similar once to me but it was related to the EBS volume of my EC2 instance. Because of a code failure it was consuming all the accumulated I/O credits.